# Add ARM Azure VM only via Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

Is it possible to add a new VM only using Terraform? All the examples/samples and everything I have used Terraform for so far has me adding the VNet, Subnet, Network Interface, VM, Storage, etc., etc. all at the same time, referencing the resources crated within the script when creating other resources. For example, Terraform the Network Interface and then reference that when creating the VM.

What about if you already have the VNet, Subnet, etc. and just want to add a new, for example, Network Interface. Every time I try to do this and just reference what I *think* is the correct id, the plan stage works but then the apply fails with an "autorest:DoErrorUnlessStatusCode 400" error on he PUT call.

Is it just not possible to do this unless the resources were originally created using Terraform?

Comment: can you share your template?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You can get the id from an created subnet with output. Like:

```
output "subnetid" {
       value = "${azurerm_subnet.xxx.id}"
}
```

In your next template you can use this id in the subnet_id field.

The value of "${azurerm_subnet.xxx.id}" is base on the resourcegroup/vnet/subnet. So if you know how it is build you can also like to resource that are not created in terraform.

Comment: The idea was to get the id from something that has already been created, outside of the current Terraform script.

Comment: If you get the url of the resource, you can use it in your script. The output just shows how it is formatted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the data directive to get existing resources as below. You can then interpolate these to create your VM.

```
data "azurerm_resource_group" "existing_deploy_rg" {
  name     = "RG"
}

data "azurerm_virtual_network" "existing_vnet" {
  name                = "existing-vnet"
  resource_group_name = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.existing_deploy_rg.name}"
}

data "azurerm_subnet" "existing_subnet" {
  name                 = "existing-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.existing_deploy_rg.name}"
  virtual_network_name = "${data.azurerm_virtual_network.existing_vnet.name}"
}
```